# XtraReport's datasource binding

Tags: c#, winforms, xtrareport

There're any way to bind data from an XtraReport's datasource to a, let's say, a DataGridView?
The target of this - before displaying a report to display it's data in UI.

Comment: What do you mean "data from an XtraReport's datasource".What is this datasource?

Comment: DevExpress XtraReports suite - base report class is XtraReport. In my case reports's datasource points to a stored procedure - so there is any possibility to get data returned by that procedure before report is displayed.

Comment: Why don't you retrieve the data before and pass it to the report -or to another form- as an argument

Answer (score 0):

1. if you mean DevExpress.XtraReports its not a dataSource, its a namespace .
2. if your referring nor wanted for DevExpress.XtraGridControl or a grid to show your data here's a link that possible shows what you can do:

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2387

- create a binding List and add items .
- make it your dataSource for grid .

Answer (score 0):

The situation is more complex that I thought, guys. So let me describe in short the workflow.

Application - a WinForms' one - has a reporting module which use Devexpress reporting tool - XtraReporting - as reporting engine. Report templates are uploaded to DB as streams and when is need to run a report - template's data is "uploaded" from DB, mapped with data and runnned. All info about reports' datasource - I mean data required by report to be displayed - is encapsulated in report template at Design-time.
Now is required that before report is displayed - it should be displayed an UI control (grid, treeview)  in order to preview data used in report - report's preview is not a variant - only UI. 
No - my question - is there any possibility to bind any WinForms UI control to XtraReport's datasource - in my case is a **DevExpress.DataAccess.Sql.SqlDataSource** witch points to a stored procedure **DevExpress.DataAccess.Sql.StoredProcQuery**.

Here is a code snippet

```
void GetData(XtraReport xReport)
{
    var dsrc = xReport.DataSource as SqlDataSource;
    if (dsrc != null)
    {
     dsrc.Fill();
    //..... - can I get data from dsrc - report's datasource ?
    }
}
```